# Unable to deploy two war files in tomcat when it is installed as a service

Tags: tomcat7, windows-server-2008

I am in a situation where I have to deploy two war files in my tomcat . Using

tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi#7.0.50

I have a windows server 2003 machine with 3GB  RAM. setenv.bat configuration is

set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xms256M -Xmx2048M %JAVA_OPTS%

Now,
What works:
When running tomcat with startup.bat. Everything runs fine the way I want.

What does not work :
I installed tomcat as a service. Made same configurations in Tomcat7w.exe . But was will not deploy , on deploying second war stage it just stucks. No errors at all.

Also, when I run tomcat as a service without war files, it runs successfully.

Can anyone please help me out.

Thanks
Arvind

Comment: I can not even see tomcat's ROOT home page in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not post many questions but I get to the answers by myslef. Should have tried more and then post here. Thank you guys if you are looking out for a solution. I fixed it by changing memory setting. I had to do a number of tests on these memory settings and finally one of them worked.

So for this deployment I kept 1024MB for XMx and perm size of 412 MB and it worked.

Cheers!